# How to retain fragment selected by navigation drawer when orientation changes? Using Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm working on android app in C#/Xamarin.

I am using only one activity, with 12 fragments. I have a navigation drawer in main activity, where selection loads one of the 12 fragments. Here is the beginning of my MainActivity class. As you can see, OnCreate loads the savedInstanceState, and only creates fragments if savedInstanceState is null.

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private SupportFragment currentFragment = new Weight_Fragment();
    private Weight_Fragment mWeightFragment;
    private Distance_Fragment mDistanceFragment;
    private Volume_Fragment mVolumeFragment;
    private Help_Fragment mHelpFragment;
    private Temperature_Fragment mTempFragment;
    private Time_Fragment mTimeFragment;
    private Data_Fragment mDataFragment;
    private Pressure_Fragment mPressureFragment;
    private Energy_Fragment mEnergyFragment;
    private Force_Fragment mForceFragment;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {           
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create UI
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);

        //Init Fragments
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            mWeightFragment = new Weight_Fragment();
            mDistanceFragment = new Distance_Fragment();
            mVolumeFragment = new Volume_Fragment();
            mHelpFragment = new Help_Fragment();
            mTempFragment = new Temperature_Fragment();
            mTimeFragment = new Time_Fragment();
            mDataFragment = new Data_Fragment();
            mPressureFragment = new Pressure_Fragment();
            mEnergyFragment = new Energy_Fragment();
            mForceFragment = new Force_Fragment();

            //Add Fragments to Manager
            var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, mHelpFragment, "Help");
            trans.Hide(mHelpFragment);
            trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, mDistanceFragment, "Distance");
            trans.Hide(mDistanceFragment);
            trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, mVolumeFragment, "Volume");
            trans.Hide(mVolumeFragment);
            trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, mTempFragment, "Temperature");
            trans.Hide(mTempFragment);
            trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, mPressureFragment, "Pressure");
            trans.Hide(mPressureFragment);
            trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, mEnergyFragment, "Energy");
            trans.Hide(mEnergyFragment);
            trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, mForceFragment, "Force");
            trans.Hide(mForceFragment);
            trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, mTimeFragment, "Time");
            trans.Hide(mTimeFragment);
            trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, mDataFragment, "Data Storage");
            trans.Hide(mDataFragment);
            trans.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, mWeightFragment, "Weight");
            trans.Commit();
            currentFragment = mWeightFragment;
        }
```

The navigation drawer switches between fragments like this:

```
void NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        switch (e.MenuItem.ItemId)
        {
            case (Resource.Id.nav_weight):
                toolbar.Title = "Weight";
                ShowFragment(mWeightFragment);
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav_distance):
                toolbar.Title = "Distance";
                ShowFragment(mDistanceFragment);
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav_volume):
                toolbar.Title = "Volume";
                ShowFragment(mVolumeFragment);
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav_temperature):
                toolbar.Title = "Temperature";
                ShowFragment(mTempFragment);
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav_pressure):
                toolbar.Title = "Pressure";
                ShowFragment(mPressureFragment);
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav_energy):
                toolbar.Title = "Energy";
                ShowFragment(mEnergyFragment);
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav_force):
                toolbar.Title = "Force";
                ShowFragment(mForceFragment);
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav_time):
                toolbar.Title = "Time";
                ShowFragment(mTimeFragment);
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.nav_data):
                toolbar.Title = "Data Storage";
                ShowFragment(mDataFragment);
                break;
            case (Resource.Id.help):
                toolbar.Title = "Help";
                ShowFragment(mHelpFragment);
                break; 
        }
```

My override of OnSaveInstanceState is very simple:

```
public override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    }
```

When device orientation changes, MainActivity is restarted, which recreates all fragments and therefore displays mWeightFragment, as it is the only one not hidden when fragments are created.

I have separate layouts for portrait and landscape orientations, so I need fragments to somehow be updated when orientation changes, so the corresponding layout will be shown. I also need the app to stay on the same fragment instead of jumping back to mWeightFragment every time the orientation changes.

After using OnSaveInstanceState and only creating the fragments the first time the activity is created, I get the following error:

Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference

But only after changing the orientation. If I simply choose a different fragment then change orientation, then change orientation back, it works fine and stays on the same fragment just like I want, but as soon as I try to change fragments again, I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest make sure you have:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" />
```

Also make sure you overtide the OnSavedInstanceState:

```
    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
    }
```

Within the class file

Comment: I added my manifest to original question. This line is already included.

Comment: thanks. How do I save the current fragment, and then reload it when the activity restarts?

Comment: @siralexsir88 Take a look at this post, it should provide you with what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12514154/1600129